# Can we customise WebView in android

Tags: android, webview, customization

Can we customise loaded website in WebView android ? I need to customise website which is loaded in the WebView .I need to add new features in the loaded website

Comment: You have got to be more specific than that. What do you mean by customize in this context?

Comment: I need to add new features in the loaded website in webview

Comment: you can try [this](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView/blob/master/Source/library/src/main/java/im/delight/android/webview/AdvancedWebView.java)

Comment: @prachisaini Did you solve a problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can inject javaScript(which can customize html for example). For this you should enable js in webview:

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Then you can call to [loadUrl](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#loadUrl(java.lang.String))() with string which is a javaScript code with prefix `javascript:` like:

```
fun runJS(webView: WebView) {
   webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert('hello')");
}
```

To run js when some page is fully loaded use `onPageFinished` of [WebViewClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient):

```
val webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
      override fun onPageFinished(webView: WebView, url: String) {
        runJS(webView)
      }
    }
webView.webViewClient = webViewClient
```

And you can call from your js code to your java code by using [addJavascriptInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)).

Pleas follow next links to get more samples:

https://medium.com/@skywall/inject-js-into-androids-webview-8845fb5902b7

https://github.com/henrychuangtw/WebView-Javascript-Inject